# Exporting route from QGIS Roadgraph plugin?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, route

I've created a route with qgis roadgraph plugin, and I want to create a  shapefile (line) from this. I've tried with export, and save as .shp, but the new shapefile doesn't show the line!

Comment: Are there any attributes in the exported shapefile?

Comment: no there aren't...

Comment: Have you tried exporting it to a **temporary file** first and then saving that as a shapefile?

Comment: okay, yesterday it didn't work, but today It works:) thanks a lot!

Comment: Haha strange and I didn't do anything :) But I'm glad it's working!